# Saving flickr images to sdcard which is displayed in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, sd-card, flickr

So far I have done `flickr` integration in my Android application.

I have displayed all the images from gallery and photostream from `flickr` account to the `GridView`.

Now, I have to Save that images to device i.e. in `sdcard`.

I have tried following code where `gvPhotos` is my `GridView` :

```
gvPhotos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Drawable drawable= null;

            drawable = view.getDrawable();


            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

            String path=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();

            File file = new File(path, "name.png");

            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

But, It gives error

> can not resolve method getDrawable()

**XML :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".PhotosActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gvPhotos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="3"></GridView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selectedImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gvPhotos"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

How can I get done this stuff ?

Comment: @Rajesh Know anyone for Solution ?

Comment: Please post your GrdView's item xml

Answer (score 2):

IMO, you should not try and save the file from the bitmap, because it may be scaled down, depending on the scaling algo you used to display the bitmap. The result may be a bad quality downloaded file. you should, instead, download the file from the HTTP server again:

```
private boolean downloadFile(String uri, String fileName) throws URISyntaxException, IOException  {

    URL url = new URL(uri);

    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        //Check for HTTP_OK on the url
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                    + " " + connection.getResponseMessage());
            return false;
        }

        long totalSize = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        input = connection.getInputStream();
        output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 50];
        long downloadedBytes = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            // allow canceling with back button
            if (isCancelled()) {
                input.close();
                return false;

            }
            downloadedBytes += count;
            //There may be a problem that the size is reported negative by the server. This is to protect for that
            if(totalSize > 0){
               publishProgress((int) (downloadedBytes * 100 / totalSize));
            }
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }

        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Wrap this up in an async task, and call this async task on your itemClick(). OR, use this in a downloaded service, to make the file download operation independent from you activity

Answer (score 1):

Error:

> can not resolve method getDrawable()

From error i can say that you are calling `getDrawable()` method on `view`.

First you have to get Clicked item's `ImageView` reference then use `ImageView.getDrawable()`

You are doing wrong in `onItemClick()` method.

You are calling

```
drawable = view.getDrawable();
```

which will not return `Drawable`.

**EDIT:**

You can try this

```
Drawable drawable= null;
ImageView im = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewXYZ);
drawable = im.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
```

where `imageViewXYZ` is id of your `GridView` inner layout's `ImageView`.

You can use this method to save Image to sd card.

```
public void saveImageToDevice(Bitmap bm) {
        try {
           String path=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
            File directory = new File(path);
            directory.mkdirs();
            String filename = "SAMPLE.png";
            File file = new File(path, filename);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            } else {
                OutputStream fOut;
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView

Comment: Please post your GrdView's item xml

Comment: You have posted main layout xml i need gvPhotos item's layout xml

Comment: Remember, that I am not setting images in gridview from Drawables. So tell me if any other way available to save those images to sdcard if you know.

Comment: tried but it gives null pointer exception at drawable = im.getDrawable();